# Split words then encapsulate, then split characters and encapsulate

Tags: arrays, excel, string, nested-loops

I try to encapsulate each word of the string in cell A1 between two curly braces '{' '}' 
and then encapsulate each letter/character of each word inside brackets '[' ']'.
So the string: "apples are sweet" becomes:

{ [a][p][p][l][e][s] } { [a][r][e] } { [s][w][e][e][t] }

The result is repeating each braced word inside the next one:

{ [a][p][p][l][e][s] } { **[a][p][p][l][e][s]**[a][r][e] } { **[a][p][p][l][e][s][a][r][e]**[s][w][e][e][t] }

The bold parts should not be there.
the result is displayed in B2.

```
Sub splitEncapsulate()

    Dim myString As String
    Dim intoStrArr() As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim myWord As String

    myString = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value
    'splits the string based on the delimeter space
    intoStrArr = Split(myString, " ")
    myWord = ""

    'loops through the string
    For i = LBound(intoStrArr) To UBound(intoStrArr)

        myWord = intoStrArr(i)

        'loop each character in myWord
         For j = 1 To Len(myWord)
             'encapsulate each character with '[ ]'
             char = "[" & Mid(myWord, j, 1) & "]"

             'group characters again
              joinedChars = joinedChars & char

         Next j

        'encapsulate each word with '{ }' and add space in between words
        newtxt = newtxt + "{ " + joinedChars + " }" + " "

    Next i
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Offset(0, 1).Value = newtxt
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd just need to reset `joinedChars`, as with each loop, it currently remains the same:

after

```
newtxt = newtxt + "{ " + joinedChars + " }" + " "
```

add

```
joinedChars = ""
```

(Using <kbd>F8</kbd> to step through the code helps a lot. That lets you see each line fire individually, so on the second loop I saw that on the first use of `joinedChars` it already held the `apples` data, so you need to clear that before using it again).

Edit: FYI you could also make this a function, in case you wanted to quickly use this on any cell.  In a Workbook module add the following:

```
Function splitEncapsulate(cel As Range)

' Enter the code here, with my suggestion above
' but replace `ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Offset(0, 1).Value = newtxt` with the next line:
splitEncapsulate = Trim(newtxt)
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Very helpful indeed this solved my problem. Thank you for the tip and for your quick response.

Answer (score 3):

You could use Regular Expressions

- Replace each character 'x' with `[x]`
- Replace each character-space sequence with `{ }`
- Add a `{` at the beginning and `}` at the end of the string

---

```
Option Explicit
Function enCapsulate(str As String)
    Dim sRes As String
    Dim RE As Object
Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Pattern = "(\S)"
    .Global = True
    sRes = .Replace(str, "[$1]")
    .Pattern = "(\S)\s+"
    sRes = .Replace(sRes, "$1 } { ")
    sRes = "{ " & Trim(sRes) & " }"
End With
enCapsulate = sRes

End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for suggestion. I will definitely give it a go as Regex is a subject I would like to learn about.

Comment: What does the `$1` do in the regex?

Comment: @BruceWayne  `$1`: [Insert the text that was last matched by capturing group number 1](http://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html)